# Is it possible to edit data in place using CListCtrl - if not, can anyone suggest an alternative control in MFC?

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I'm designing a MFC app in which I'd like to have a grid with 2 coloumns : both editable in which the user will input data and the app will get notified about it. The number of rows can be increased/decreased by the user as he wants - What would be the ideal MFC control to use for this kind of requirement ?

This is my first time designing a MFC app , so dont mind if it sounds too noobish :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a noobish question. Actually you have encountered a problem which bugs every MFC developer since 15 years: The MFC library does not have a built-in Grid Control. And a kind of Grid Control is what you are looking for, I guess. As far as I'm aware of, it is not possible to edit two columns in a CListCtrl. Only the first column, the "Label", can be edited.

For a Grid control you have to look for appropriate Third-Party tools which can be added to your projects, for instance as ActiveX controls. (I remember that the old Visual Studio 6 came with an "MS FlexGrid" which you could add with the component gallery to the project, but I've never worked with it, so I don't know if it's a good choice. But perhaps enough for your purpose.) Most third-party Grid controls require license fees but here is one (quite powerful) grid for free (at least free of fees but not of a license):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gridctrl.aspx

(or google by "MFC Grid Control" or something like that. I think there will be more free grids.)

Comment: Another free MFC grid control: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateGrid.aspx

Comment: Problem is, I'm developing an internal tool to be used within the company - I don't think people will be happy with a tool using third-party code as it would require all kinds of licensing hassles. Unless that is, it is absolutely necessary - and its not, just that it'll make things a lot more intuitive for users of the app. Thanks for the response - saved me time hunting down something that doesn't exist in MSVC 8.0 !!

Comment: The license for the grids linked in my answer and in adam's comment is very generous ("The Code Project Open License (CPOL)": http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx). Actually I don't see any serious restrictions, neither in commercial nor internal nor open source projects. There is even not a need to tell your users that you are using these third-party tools. I'd install it together with your app (as part of your app) and that's it.